# Using named pipe to get process substitution exit codes

Tags: bash, pipe, exit-status, fifo, process-substitution

I have a script with a fairly complex command with several process substitutions and I need to get the exit codes from the commands in the process substitutions. I'm trying to do so via a named pipe but I'm running into issues since I've never used named pipes before.

For example, given this command:

```
somecommand <(someothercommand; echo $? > named_pipe) <(someothercommand; echo $? > named_pipe) &
```

what would be the correct way of waiting for the `somecommand` to finish and reading from the `named_pipe` all of the exit codes (assuming I don't know how many exit codes will actually be written to the `named_pipe`)? So far my attempts have resulted in blocking `somecommand` (since I'm assuming it's waiting for something to read from the `named_pipe`) or only reading one exit code.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't seem too simple to do, actually. It would probably be best if the shell provided support for waiting on the process substitutions, but I don't think Bash does that.

The other problem is that the named pipe can't know how many lines you're going to write there. The pipe will read an EOF when all writers are closed, but you're likely to get one for each `echo` writing there. Unless they hit at the exact same time, in which case you don't.

But it seems possible to arrange the process substitutions to have a writing fd open from the start, so that the EOF appears only once after they're all finished.

Something like this, with `echo somecommand` and `true` and `false` standing for the actual commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(mktemp -d)
p="$dir/p"
mkfifo "$p"

# whole subshell sent to the background
(exec 3> "$p"; 
 # both process substitutions get a copy of fd 3
 echo somecommand \
    <(false; echo "cmd1: $?" >&3) \
    <(true;  echo "cmd2: $?" >&3) \

) &

# read the exit statuses, this will see EOF once all the three
# background processes above finish
cat "$p"
rm -rf "$dir" 2>/dev/null
```

Note that the order of the lines printed to the pipe depends on the timing  and is essentially random.

Also, if `echo somecommand` is slow to run, the output from `cat "$p"` can appear first. You'd need to read the data from the pipe to a variable, and then `wait` for the background process afterwards.

There's also a possibility without backgrounding `somecommand`, but it needs some more gymnastics with the filehandles:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(mktemp -d)
p="$dir/p"
mkfifo "$p"

# open an fd for read+write (doesn't block because both open)
exec 3<>"$p"

# process substs inherit the fd, closing it when they exit
echo somecommand \
    <(false; echo "cmd1: $?" >&3) \
    <(true;  echo "cmd2: $?" >&3) \

# open another reader to keep the pipe live
exec 4<"$p"

# now we can close the writing handle
exec 3>&-

# read the data off
cat <&4
exec 4<&-

rm -rf "$dir" 2>/dev/null
```

It may be more straightforward to just collect the exit statuses to a regular file and read it until a known amount of lines appears.

```
#!/bin/bash

f=$(mktemp)

# number of process substitutions
n=2
echo somecommand \
    <(false; echo "cmd1: $?" >>"$f") \
    <(true;  echo "cmd2: $?" >>"$f") \

exec 3< "$f"
# read that many lines
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)) do
    # if the data isn't there yet, retry reading until a new line appears
    until read line <&3; do sleep 1; done
    echo "$line";
done 
exec 3<&-

rm -f "$f"
```

As far as I tested, all three seem to work, but working with process substitutions and pipes can be hairy enough, so I may have missed some failure mode.